# How can I to empty the content of html tag?

Tags: vue.js

Hello I am loading a few of data each API call, inside a tag, but when I do the second call this data is appended to the data of the previous call.

The question is how can I clear the content of a div?

I am using this for select that div

```
this.$refs.data
```

In order to add contet I am using the following code:

```
responseJSON.forEach(element => {
        let card = Vue.extend(card)
        let instance = new card({
          propsData: {
            ch: element
          }
        })
        instance.$mount()
        this.$refs.aaa.appendChild(instance.$el)
        this.cards.push(instance)
      });
```

Comment: can you add more code related to how you put your HTML and data in Vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the `responseJSON.forEach`, you can clear everything in the div first by running

```
this.$refs.data.innerHTML = ""
```